# I am using iOS InAppPurchaseManager

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

with phonegap 1.5.0rc1 and XCode 4.3.
I can not upgrade my mac for the moment.

When I use plugins I do not have any answer, no alert and no message.

I try to do this :

```
function onDeviceReady() {

                processdiv = document.getElementById('processdiv');
                processdiv.innerHTML = "Loading...";


                window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onPurchased = function(transactionIdentifier, productId, transactionReceipt) {
                    console.log('purchased: ' + productId);
                    /* Give coins, enable subscriptions etc */
                }

                processdiv.innerHTML += "<br />onPurchased OK";

                window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onRestored = function(transactionIdentifier, productId, transactionReceipt) {
                    console.log('restored: ' + productId);
                    /* See the developer guide for details of what to do with this */
                }

                processdiv.innerHTML += "<br />onRestored OK";

                window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.onFailed = function(errno, errtext) {
                    console.log('failed: ' + errtext);                  
                }

                processdiv.innerHTML += "<br />onFailed OK";


            }

            function requestProdData(prodStr) {


                window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.requestProductData(prodStr, function(productId, title, description, price) {
                            console.log("productId: " + productId + " title: " + title + " description: " + description + " price: " + price);
                            showAlert("productId: " + productId + " title: " + title + " description: " + description + " price: " + price);
                            window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.makePurchase(productId, 1);
                        }, function(id) {
                            console.log("Invalid product id: " + id);
                            showAlert("par la ?? " + id);
                        }
                    );

                processdiv.innerHTML = "ProductID: " + prodStr + "<br />";  


            }
```

Help
I try to add alert in different place of code to know what is the problem.
I had many products in a test app.

I search example to use this plugins. Thanks.

Comment: Do not foget to add plugins inAppPurchaseManager in you plugins Cordova.plist :(

Comment: Title != first half of first sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not foget to add plugins inAppPurchaseManager in you plugins Cordova.plist :(